# Finding the simple polygon of largest perimeter given a set of dots with coordinates on a plane

Tags: python, math, geometry

The polygon has to be composed of all the n dots. It is guaranteed that any three of the dots are not collinear. Right now, I could only come up with the brute force algorithm. I wonder if there is another way to tackle this problem. The volume of the dots set could be as large as 10^5.
Any idea is welcome :)

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks like a version of the travelling salesman problem. Basically, if you have a set of `N` planar points `p1, p2, ..., pN`, you can think they form the vertices of a graph and that between any two of them `pi pj` there is an edge (interpreted as a straight-line segment) connecting the two points, so it is a fully connected graph of `N` points (combinatorially, it is equivalent to the `N` dimensional symplex). Furthermore, one can assign a weigh on each edge of this graph, the weight being the distance between the two points that it connects (i.e. the length of the straight-line segment connecting the two points). Now, the goal is to find a Hamiltonian cyclic path that maximizes the sum of the weights on the edges that it contains. On top of that, there is the further restriction that that the cyclic path has to be a simple planar cycle, so you have to discard any solution you get that self-intersects.

I believe this is a tough problem so maybe start with Wikipedia:  [The Longest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) and [The Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and check some of the exact, heuristic and approximation algorithms that are mentioned there.